# How write a compound Hamcrest statement (with a logical "or" operation)

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

How would I go about writing the following JUnit assert with Hamcrest?

```
assertTrue(var1 == 5 || var2 == 10);
```

I can't use the `anyOf()` matcher wrapper because I dont need multiple matchers, I need multiple statements, one for each variable `var1` and `var2`

Comment: Are you saying you aren't allowed to use `org.junit.Assert.assertTrue` anymore?

Comment: @azurefrog i want to stop using `assertTrue` and start using hamcrest matchers

Comment: It's not possible until var1 and var2 are properties of a single object, because a Hamcrest matcher verifies only one object.

Comment: @StefanBirkner thank you, I was hoping it was possible in hamcrest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write this as a single Hamcrest assertion by turning your variables into a single composite object:

```
assertThat(ImmutableList.of(var1, var2),
    either(contains(is(5), anything()))
    .or(contains(anything(), is(10))));
```

I would suggest that this is not particularly easy to understand, nor does it help explain what this would mean and why this represents success.